# Webpack Bundle Not Executing

Tags: webpack, nrwl-nx, nxjs

I created a bundle using webpack (Nx's Webpack executor to be more exact) and it is bundling the code in a way that **requires** it to be explicitly called by some other script, rather than self-executing. However, when I bundle the same exact code using webpack-cli directly, it works as expected and self-executes... the way it was written.

When running the build command I'm getting variations that don't self-execute. I've played with various webpack config options such as `output.module`, `output.chunkFormat`, `externalsType`, etc. to try to get this this working. However, as you can see, the outputs are not self-executing:

**Bad Output (Example 1)**

```
(self["webpackChunk"] = self["webpackChunk"] || []).push([[923],{

/***/ 38147:
/***/ (() => {

console.log('TRYING ANYTHING');


/***/ })

},
/******/ __webpack_require__ => { // webpackRuntimeModules
/******/ var __webpack_exec__ = (moduleId) => (__webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = moduleId))
/******/ var __webpack_exports__ = (__webpack_exec__(38147));
/******/ }
]);
```

OR with slightly different settings

**Bad Output (Example 2)**

```
{

/***/ 38147:
/***/ (() => {

console.log('TRYING ANYTHING');


/***/ })

}
```

When I bundle directly using webpack-cli (`webpack --config ./foo/webpack.config.js --mode production`), it bundles as expected:

**Good Output**

```
/******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
var __webpack_exports__ = {};
console.log('TRYING ANYTHING');

/******/ })();
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The build script uses a webpack.config that **exports a function** which then returns a merged config object. However, webpack-cli uses a webpack.config file that exports an object **not** a function. Not sure if this is an important distinction.

Is there some configuration option I'm missing here? Why is one bundling in a self-executing fashion and the other exports a map of function(s) that expects to be referenced directly:

```
{
  38146: () => {
    console.log('TRYING ANYTHING');
  }
}

// This would need to get called somewhere... somehow?
38146();
```

Comment: Having a similar issue. What did you change to get the "Example 2" output? And did you manage to get this to work with nx in the meantime?